# Typescirpt mapped typed in redux reducer factory typings problem

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings, mapped-types

I'm trying to achieve type-safe function to create reducers based on "action handlers" map. The idea is to have API that will look like this:

```
export const Actions = {
    setToken: (token: string) => createAction(SET_TOKEN_TYPE, token),
    invalidateToken: () => createAction(INVALIDATE_TOKEN_TYPE),
    startLogin: () => createAction(START_LOGIN_TYPE)
};

export const reducer = createReducer<State, typeof Actions>(
    {
        [SET_TOKEN_TYPE]: ({ loginError, ...state }, action) => ({
            ...state,
            token: action.payload,
            loading: false
        }),
        [INVALIDATE_TOKEN_TYPE]: ({ token, ...state }) => state,
        [START_LOGIN_TYPE]: ({ loginError, ...state }) => ({
            ...state,
            loading: true
        })
    },
    {
        loading: false
    }
);
```

`createReducer` function should (without Typescript for clarity) look then like this:

```
function createReducer(handlers, initialState) {
    return (state = initialState, action) => {
        if (action.type in handlers) {
            return handlers[action.type](state, action);
        }
        return state;
    };
}
```

I created such typed function to have type-safety:

```
interface Action<T extends string> {
    type: T;
}
type ActionCreator<T extends string> = (...args: any) => Action<T>;
type ActionsCreators = {
    [creator: string]: ActionCreator<any>;
};
type ActionsUnion<Actions extends ActionsCreators> = ReturnType<
    Actions[keyof Actions]
>;
type ActionHandlers<ActionCreators extends ActionsCreators, State> = {
    [K in ReturnType<ActionCreators[keyof ActionCreators]>["type"]]: (
        state: State,
        action: ReturnType<ActionCreators[K]> 
    ) => State
};

    function createReducer<State, Actions extends ActionsCreators>(
    handlers: ActionHandlers<Actions, State>,
    initialState: State
) {
    return (
        state: State = initialState,
        action: ActionsUnion<Actions>
    ): State => {
        if (action.type in handlers) {
            // unfortunately action.type is here any :(
            return handlers[action.type](state, action); // here I have the error
        }
        return state;
    };
}
```

In the `handlers[action.type]` I have error (with `noImplicitAny: true`)

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ActionHandlers' has no index signature.

Any idea how to have typed `action.type` inside reducer?

You can find the whole example in [the gist](https://gist.github.com/mlewando/e578e28e1c0584ce28a1fc3d30a7f377)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the error is `action.type` is typed as `any` implicitly since there was no applicable type applied.

At some point in the chain you use `any` as a type parameter for something that needs to be rooted in `string`:

```
type ActionsCreators = {
    [creator: string]: ActionCreator<any>;
};
```

If you add a type parameter here you can replace the `any`; however, you will need to pass it all the way down the line.

See the below version where this update has been made. I had to rename some of the intermediate types to generic names (`T` or `P`) since I was having a hard time keeping the typings straight.

With the extra type parameter `<P>`, we now have a type for the following instead of implicit `any`:

```
const f = handlers[action.type];
```

here, `f` becomes `ActionHandlers<P, T, State>[P]`

```
export interface Action<T extends string> {
    type: T;
}

export interface ActionWithPayload<T extends string, P> extends Action<T> {
    payload: P;
}

export type ActionCreator<T extends string> = (...args: any) => Action<T>;

export type ActionsCreators<T extends string> = {
    [creator: string]: ActionCreator<T>;
};

export type ActionsUnion<P extends string, T extends ActionsCreators<P>> = ReturnType<T[keyof T]>;

export type ActionHandlers<P extends string, T extends ActionsCreators<P>, State> = {
    [K in ReturnType<T[keyof T]>["type"]]: (
        state: State,
        action: ReturnType<T[K]>
    ) => State
};

export function createReducer<P extends string, State, T extends ActionsCreators<P>>(
    handlers: ActionHandlers<P, T, State>,
    initialState: State
) {
    return (state: State = initialState, action: ActionsUnion<P, T>): State => {

        if (action.type in handlers) {
            const f = handlers[action.type];
            return f(state, action);
        }

        return state;
    };
}
```